# Redirect to store link in tablets doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, mobile, deep-linking

My mobile application has a banner to open app store or play store from the app. I am using user agent to identify the OS. The banner works fine. It opens app if the app is installed and redirects to the store otherwise on mobile web view. On iPad and other tablets, clicking the banner opens the app if installed, however, it does not redirect to the store if the app is not installed. Can anyone explain if the app store and play store link is different for mobile and tablets? Or is there anything wrong with my piece of code? Thank you.

```
vm.redirectToStore = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") > -1) {
            window.location.href = "itms-apps://apps.apple.com/us/app/{{appName}}/{{id}}";
        } else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1) {
            window.location.href = "market://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={{appId}}";
        }
    }, 25);
    window.location.href = "{{appId}}://";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your iPad user agent?
In the code above you only cover the cases of `iPhone` and `android`

See in https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_platform/ipad/

Those user agents for iPad contain the `iPad` word instead of `iPhone`.

Comment: Yeah. For iPads, the user agent  should be compared with "iPad". You are right. But the android tablets and mobiles both have "Android" on user agent. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: User agents are tricky stuff. Even in Android, when all user agents have "android" inside, you'll see that some browsers behave differently, and then you need to apply a different strategy for deep linking or redirect to store.

e.g. Chrome in Android will require to use intents and not URI schemes.